# Getting twitter stream using nodejs twit npm

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am following the link [Twit NPM](https://github.com/ttezel/twit)

to get access to twitter stream .

I do the following

```
var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         'key',
    consumer_secret:      'key',
    access_token:         'key',
    access_token_secret:  'key'
});

var stream = T.stream('statuses/sample.json');

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet)
});
```

And i get Bad Request Error 401 . Not sure why ,because if i use curl it works.

Answer (score 1):

ok i figured out. The time on my laptop was 5mins faster that actual time, which was making the call with future timestamp and thus failing.